# Why is self in closure not referring to the owning class instance?

Tags: swift, closures

In the code below, the print statement outputs "C2", which is the class that is creating the closure being passed as an init argument to C1.

```
class C1 {
    let closure: () -> Void
    init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

class C2 {
    func test() {
        let c1 = C1(closure: { [unowned self] in
            // I would expect "self" to be the C1 instance
            print(type(of:self))
        })
        c1.closure()
    }
}
C2().test()
```

I was expecting "self" to be the C1 instance. Why is it not that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what your expectation would be if you wrote your code like this:

```
class C2 {
    func test() {
        let closure = { [unowned self] in
            print(type(of:self))
        })
        let c1 = C1(closure: closure)
        c1.closure()
    }
}
```

They are essentially doing the same thing, but your version just compresses it into one line.  But you are still creating a closure parameter within the scope of the `test()` method of the type `C2`.  Even though you have in on a single line, the closure parameter must still be fully created and exist in the scope of the `test()` method *before* C1 is ever instantiated with it.